# Get the privileges of root with the user with I do an exploit with Shellshock

Tags: metasploit, privilege-escalation, meterpreter, shellshock

I got the remote control of a linux machine with Shellshock attack in Kali Linux (attacker machine) to a TinyCore Linux (victim machine), I used this module to attack the CGI vulnerability:

`use exploit/multi/http/apache_mod_cgi_bash_env_exec`

When I'm inside the machine I want to get the root privilege with my user, by default Shellshock doesn't gives you the root user, but I want to transform my user to the root privileges, I've tried this with `sudo` controls but my shell meterpreter doesn't recognize that command options, is there an alternative way of get the privileges of the root with the user that I obtain in Metasploit?

Could be a working option change the user that I have (consulting `getuid`) to 0:0 in the `/etc/passwd` password fields in the file?

Comment: This question is too broad. Privilege escalation is not a simple and always standard process. Also meterpreter doesn't recognize `sudo` as a command simply because it's not a meterpreter command but a shell command, you have to be in a shell to be able to use `sudo`.

Comment: _Could be a working option change the user that I have to 0:0 in the /etc/passwd_: You cannot, because you need _root_ to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to identify and exploit a [privilege escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) vulnerability on the machine.